# Is it true this problem cannot be solved with linear programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

A paraphrasing of the relevant information:

*An oil company produces two types of oil, X and Y. The refinery is to buy four different sorts of crude oil which when refined result in three halfproducts A, B, C according to the following table:*

\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Crude\;oil\;type & A & B & C \\
\hline
1 & 0.8 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
\hline
2 & 0.3 & 0.3 & 0.4 \\
\hline
3 & 0.7 & 0.1 & 0.2 \\
\hline
3 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.1 \\
\hline
\end{array}

*These halfproducts will then make up the final products X, Y.*

Further given are the prices of the oils and crudes, which are not relevant to my question. I am then asked to maximise profits. My problem is the following:

The first four variables $(r_{1}, r_{2}, r_{3}, r_{4})$ signify the amount of the crude oils that are to be bought. Without loss of generality, start with A. Let $A(r_{1}, r_{2}, r_{3}, r_{4})$ be a function dependent on these variables that gives the usable amount of the halfproduct A. You would then want to determine how to mix the final products X, Y from the halfproducts A, B, C. Say z% of A is mixed into X, this then leaves (100-z)% of A to be mixed into Y. But the final amount of X would now be given by $X = \frac{z}{100} \cdot A(r_{1}, r_{2}, r_{3}, r_{4}) \cdots$. Because this is a part of the function that is to be maximised, the model is no longer linear, and can therefore not be solved by linear programming.

Am I correct in saying this problem cannot by solved using linear programming, or is there another way of constructing a relevant model?

---

edit: the full assignment - **note this assignment will be graded, so please restrict your reply to a directive answer**

*An oil company produces two types of oil X and Y, costing \$0.18 and \$0.21 respectively. The refinery is to buy four 
different sorts of crude oil which when refined result in three halfproducts A, B, C according to the following table:*

\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Crude\;oil\;type & A & B & C \\
\hline
1 & 0.8 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
\hline
2 & 0.3 & 0.3 & 0.4 \\
\hline
3 & 0.7 & 0.1 & 0.2 \\
\hline
3 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.1 \\
\hline
\end{array}

*The price of the crude oiles are \$0.14 for type 1, \$0.10 for type 2, \$0.15 for type 3 and \$0.12 for type 4. Oil Y should consist
of halfproduct A for at least 60%, and C may make up at most 35% of Y. The only restriction on X is that C may make up at most 30%
of X. When mixing A, B and C, 2% of A and 1% of B and C get lost due to evaporation. The refinery can process at most 100.000 liters
of crude oil per day. Determine the optimal production scheme.*

Comment: Please post the whole exercise. There should be a table which shows the relation between $A,B,C$ and $X,Y$.

Comment: The problem can be linearized. If you give your exact model, I can help you do that.

Comment: Ive edited in the full assignment.